# PostgreSQL could not start postgresql.service using root user due to postmaster.pid does not exist

Tags: linux, postgresql, redhat

I have tried execute the pg_ctl start using postgres user and it works, but when I try to start the postgresql service from root user, it failed with the following error log

> pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist

I don't have any clue what the cause is. anyone ever face this problem?

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete message.  Please show the full command you ran and complete output.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/server-start.html) say:

*Whatever you do, the server must be run by the PostgreSQL user account and not by root or any other user.*

Comment: This means to be able to run the postgre service automatically, I have to use Postgresql user?

Comment: Startup scripts generally run as root and change themselves into the desired user.